# How to manage ASP.NET Core bundleconfig.json for multiple environments?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, bundling-and-minification

What's the best practice for using the ASP.NET Core `bundleconfig.json` with development versus production environments? The prior bundler ([BundleCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundlecollection(v=vs.110).aspx)) would pay attention to the DEBUG compiler directive and not minify the list of scripts when you're debugging.

It appears as though the new paradigm is to have `<environment>` tags in the HTML templates that test for the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value. Though I don't see a way of incorporating that environment variable into the `bundleconfig.json` workflow.

One way I see is to maintain 2 lists for each bundle output in `bundleconfig.json`, minified and non-minified versions, so that the JavaScript can be debugged. Alternatively I could put direct links to the unbundled JavaScript in the development `<environment>` tag and then reference the bundled and minified version in the production/staging `<environment>` tag.

Either way there's a need to maintain 2 lists of JavaScript files (and all this goes for CSS files as well). That seems like a step backwards to me, where before you only needed to maintain a single list of source files and the the BundleCollection would only minify when appropriate.

Am I missing something here or do I need to go a step further and investigate Gulp to be able to handle the different environments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found my answer. I was about to create an HTML helper to read the `bundleconfig.json` for the development environment, but it appears I'm not the first one to think this was a good idea. Note that the .NET Core implementation is linked to at the bottom of the page

https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/wiki/Unbundling-scripts-for-debugging

**Edit**

For the .NET Core implementation, the reference to the `bundleconfig.json` was expecting it to be in a /Configs folder, which may or may not be the case in your project. For me, I just had it in the root of the project.

**Edit**

So this doesn't work if the source files are outside of the wwwroot folder. Having files outside of the wwwroot folder is completely reasonable, so I'm investigating having the html helper point to a path that will stream the files in debug mode

**Possible Solution**

Here's my evolution of the solution:

https://gist.github.com/rupe120/512a9eb837383963f80fd9ef4984eb15

**Update**

I modified my solution to use `{*filePath}` in the route definition, so there's now no need to encode the path

**Update**

I think this is the last major update I'll do. I replaced the static base route string with the `outputFileName` values from the `bundleconfig.json`. So now there's as many debug routes as there will be minified files and no fear what so ever of name collisions. Additionally you can see what files are included in which bundle when you're debugging, which I think is pretty cool.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't exactly call this a best practice but the following works for me.

In the `bundleconfig.json` I prepare one bundle for development and one for production.
Bundle for development is just concatenated text, which is easy to read and debug.
Bundle for production is minified and may optionally include source map.

```json
{
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/script.bundle.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
      "wwwroot/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "wwwroot/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false,
      "renameLocals": false
    }
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/script.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/script.bundle.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    // Optionally generate .map file
    "sourceMap": false
  }
```

The point is, that production bundle use only development bundle. That way I have to keep only one list.

On the page, where JS is needed, I add tags for two bundles.

```xml
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="script.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="script.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</environment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im with Josh on this one, seems like madness having to maintain two lists. Has anybody come back with a better build in solution without using a MvcHtmlString helper!

"sourceMap": true

This enables debugging into your js in if enabled in the bundleconfig.json
but I have noticed if you are going bundling it does not generate the maps correctly, references the combined and the each mapped file...

Smidge seems to provide this functionality - with a simple flag - debug="true"

```html
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="my-awesome-js-bundle" type="text/javascript" debug="true"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="my-awesome-js-bundle" type="text/javascript"></script>
</environment>
```

Webpack or gulp is the way to go - which one, that`s debatable.

Comment: This is not a new question... More of an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I selected the wrong reason. I'm not very comfortable with post that contain only an external link as an answer (especially since those doesn't often persist in time). It's better to add quotes and code snippets in the answer directly (eventually in addition to these links).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach for bundleconfig.json file in .Net Core is Smidge,
below links provide easier examples to implement it in projects

https://dotnetthoughts.net/runtime-bundling-and-minification-in-aspnet-core-with-smidge/
https://github.com/Shazwazza/Smidge