# ASP.NET Core 2 bundleconfig.json bind to environment variable

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm currently working on an ***ASP.NET Core 2.1.4*** MVC application.

I try to figure out, weather it is possible to bind a property from the ***bundleconfig.json*** file to an environment variable?

```
[
    ... more bundleconfig options
    // Problem:
    // Map file only if environment variable = Development; 
    // if(env.IsDevelopment)
    "sourceMap": true
    // else if(env.IsProducts) "sourceMap" : false
  }
]
```

Do you know if it's possible to change sourceMap parameter according to an environment variable?

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48097379/2309376